# Squaring a matrix using a linear memory

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

I have a N x N matrix (let's denote it with **A**). I want to calculate $A ^ 2$, using $\theta(N)$ memory (speed does not matter as long as it's a polynomial) on one processor.

I believe that this can not be done but I'm having hard times proving it.

My idea so far was as follows:

Let's say that I have an algorithm that can do it. Let **B** = $A ^ 2$. Let $x_1, ..., x_{N^2}$ be variables that represent the entities of **A**. For every variable there exists a vector with length of **N** that represents the calculations that one needs to perform to get the new value of that variable in **B**. Then we must partition these $N ^ 2$ variables in $\theta(N)$ disjoint sets (strongly related components) so that the vector associated with each variable depends only on the variables in that variable's component. And so on..., but I'm starting to get a little confused with my own approach : /

Can you give me an idea or a link to a paper?

EDIT:

Ok, I'm sorry. My overall memory on the computer is $N^2 + \theta(N)$ which means that I will use $N^2$ for **A** and I can use the rest for any kind of storage that I may need. So I need an in-place algorithm (thanks @Algebraic Pavel) - meaning that I need to use the memory where I keep **A** to store **B**. And yes - that way I'll be losing information for **A** during the computation of **B**.

If **A** was a symmetrical this can be achieved with ease, but **A** does not have any special properties in my case.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "linear memory"? Do you want to compute $A^2$ in-place or you have a separate storage for $A^2$?

Comment: Thanks for the question - I've updated my question : ) (I'll rewrite the whole question later on)

Comment: "...that way I'll be losing information..." I'm afraid that this might be a problem.

Comment: I know and I want to prove it. Maybe there's way to calculate a set of things that is independent from any other operation. For example - maybe I can calculate some elements (using the given memory) and the old values of these elements will not be needed in future operations.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't $\theta(N^3)$ **way more** than just  $\theta(N^2)$ to hold $A$ and then another $\theta(N)$ of linear working memory? I.e. $\theta(N^2) + \theta(N) \neq \theta(N^3)$.

Comment: OMG - what a giant typo :D